# How to delete a line that contains the dot character using sed

Tags: file, text, sed, text-files

I try to delete from a text file lines that contain the `.` character.

I try this command, but it does not work:

```
sed '/./d' input.txt > output.txt
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

```
sed '/\./d' input.txt > output.txt
```

I think you need to escape the dot.